# Let the user edit some value,but not all

Tags: c#

I am writing a sudoko program, I want the user to edit certain values in the array,but not the values which are already there. how do I initialize the array?

Comment: Define "are already there"

Comment: class :  value:integer state=(enabled or desabled)

Comment: You already opened a similar question today, did you not?

Comment: m1o2 It was not clear so i have removed that and come up with this.

Comment: @JeevaMahendran Did you thought about using an indexer for a custom class? In the indexer you could decide and check whether the user can change a certain value or not.

Comment: @m1o2 I have not tried, but even indexers are handy in these situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach your problem with multiple solutions, all of which relay on the same principle -> Having your number coupled with a boolean.


You can write it down with a class:

```
public class SudokuCell
{
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
    private int _value;
    public int Value 
    { 
        get { return _value; }
        set { if (IsEditable) _value = value; }
}
```

or a struct:

```
public struct SudokuCell
{
    public bool IsEditable;
    public int Value;
}
```

and have a `List` or an `Array` of `SudokuCell`s that you can use as your data structure or you can use a lazier method and write it down using `Tuple`:

```
List<Tuple<int, bool>> sudokuCells = new List<Tuple<int,bool>>();
```

Then whenever you want to change the value you can check it's corresponding `bool` and you instantly know whether you can or can't change it (assuming you set it when you initialize your sudoku)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to overcome your problem is to use 2 multidimensional arrays, the first one to save the value and the second one to check whether some cell can be edited by the user or not..

```
int[,] ValueArray= new int[4,4];
boolean[,] EditedArray= new boolean[4,4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sudoku user edits your UI, not your array. Make the UI element read-only when the associated data should be read-only.